# How to Mount Western My Book Live Duo

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I have been reading everything I can to do this and have come to the conclusion that there are too many things I don't understand to make sense of it so finally asking a question.

Goal: I want to mount a folder on WD My Book Live Duo (mbld) so I can use it from application file/folder Open dialogs. Most urgently I need to do a directory comparison using Meld.

I can mount and bookmark it via Files, but it does not appear in a file open dialog.
I have read about 'mounting' it but have not been able to figure it out.
I can get to it from Ubuntu via a Windows workgroup.
Looking in the windows workgroup I see the location as smb://yudmtry/

First question: I don't know how to find the IP address. I have seen recommendations to use a Windows or Mac machine but I don't have one.

Second question: I have read that samba is the easiest way to mount it. Is this the case for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 which I am using?

Comment: The IP of your PC or the WD HDD?

Comment: IP of the WD HDD

Comment: You could find it by logging into your router and looking at the client list.

Comment: Thank you Andriod Dev I should have know that one. I'm working on my second question now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question: Run `hostname -I` <--- CaSe SeNsItIvE

Answer to your second question: Samba is a network mount. Are you trying to mount it locally, or over the LAN?